# Mysql how to combine having() with min()

Tags: mysql

I need to select all branches from branches table grouped by store_id order by distance

In other words i need to get the nearest branch of each store

```
select distinct  `branch_id`, `store_id`, `branch_name`,  distance 
from `store_branches` 
groupBy store_id having MIN(distance) 
orderBy `distance` asc
```

MIN(distance) couse the query to return an empty result

I used having  because orderBy is not doing the job ,because groupBy is applied before orderBy

Comment: Having `MIN()` as what?

Comment: MIN distance : having  the smallest value of distance

Comment: `HAVING` means something different from what you're expecting. It's a condition like `WHERE`. You're asking for something that has a non-zero minimum, but you don't care what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a correlated subquery:

```
select sb.`branch_id`, sb.`store_id`, sb.`branch_name`, sb.distance 
from `store_branches` sb
where sb.`distance` = (select min(distance) from `store_branches` where `store_id` = sb.`store_id`)
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select sb.`branch_id`, sb.`store_id`, sb.`branch_name`, sb.distance 
from `store_branches` sb
where not exists (
  select 1 from `store_branches`
  where `store_id` = sb.`store_id` and `distance` < sb.`distance`
)
```

For MySql 8.0 you could use `RANK()` window function:

```
select sb.`branch_id`, sb.`store_id`, sb.`branch_name`, sb.distance 
from (
  select *, rank() over (partition by `store_id` order by `distance`) rnk
  from `store_branches`
) sb
where sb.rnk = 1
```